# How to convert pdf to xlsx using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am trying to convert a pdf file to an excel file (xlsx) using excel VBA.

The problem is the code seems to be perfectly fine as I have seen it working on other computers in action, but for some reason, I am getting a run time error and I am trying to solve this for a week.

Below is the code

```
 Option Explicit
Function ClearCipboard()
'Early binding will requires a Reference to 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'
    Dim oData                 As Object    'New MSForms.DataObject

    Set oData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    oData.SetText Text:=Empty
    oData.PutInClipboard
    Set oData = Nothing
End Function
Sub Automate()

Dim PathforPDFfiles As String
Dim PathforExcelfiles As String

PathforPDFfiles = "C:\Users\kvenkat2\Desktop\Trails 18.06.2021\Test File Excel\PDF-to-Excel-Converter\"
PathforExcelfiles = "C:\Users\kvenkat2\Desktop\Trails 18.06.2021\Test File Excel\PDF-to-Excel-Converter\"

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim myFile As File

Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(PathforPDFfiles)

Dim WordApp As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim WordRange As Object

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
'Set WordDoc = WordApp.documents.Add
'Set WordApp = New Word.Application
WordApp.Visible = True

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
Set WordDoc = WordApp.documents.Open(myFile.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
Set WordRange = WordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
WordRange.WholeStory

Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
WordRange.Copy
nsh.Paste
nwb.SaveAs (PathforExcelfiles & Replace(myFile.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearCipboard
WordDoc.Close True
nwb.Close True
Next

WordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

Application.displayAlters = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox ("Done for real")
End Sub
```

`Set WordDoc = WordApp.documents.Open(myFile.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")`

This is the part where my code stops running and I try to see the opened word and nothing happens from here. I am unable to get past this line.

It shows as a run time error as shown in the image [image]

Comment: Nothing to do with VBScript or VB.Net please tag questions appropriately.

Comment: Your code will try to process _all_ files in the specified directory.  When you get the error,  have you checked which file is being processed?  Is it a PDF? If so, is it actually corrupt?

Comment: @chrisneilsen It is a PDF and I have only one PDF. The pdf is definitely not corrupted. I think it is something to do with my MS office 365 and I tried dabbling with the word trust center settings and nothing seems to work

Comment: Do you get the same error when you open the file manually in Word?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, I don't get any when I open word manually. Its when I try to run this code